# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 Error while using AVFoundation

Tags: ios5, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to use AVFoundation Framework to create a video thumbnail. I have correctly added and imported `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.` Here is the code for creating the thumbnail:

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }
    [imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //UIImage *thumbImg=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

When I build this, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds", referenced from:
  -[photojournal generateImage] in photojournal.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've reviewed similar questions on Google and here on Stack Overflow, and the consensus seems to be to add missing files to compile sources. My question is - what are the missing files for AVFoundation? Shouldn't they all come when I import the Framework?  Thanks.

Comment: yes you should only need the import statement as well as the "Link binaries with libraries" in your build phases.  Which should be automatic if you added the framework

Comment: That's what I thought. So why is it not recognizing _CMTimeMakeWithSeconds? If I comment out this line, the app compiles correctly.

Comment: On both device and simulator... and now it's still happening even though I've upgraded to iOS 6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the Core Media framework to your project, and

```
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMEdia.h>
```

CMTime is part of the Core Media framework. I had the same error and this solved it.

Comment: I already had #import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h> in the class header file, and I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

To expand on andrewmobile answer. In addition to #import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h> you will also need to add CoreMedia.framework in "Link binary with libraries" under build phases.